# determine the powers and roots of given complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Determine the powers and roots of given complex numbers using de Moivre's theorem:
$(6+5i)^5$ and $(4+3i)^{1/2}$.

I tried for powers -- it will be $5$ and $1/2$ respectively -- but I am not sure about the answers, and then I don't know how to proceed for roots of given complex numbers.  Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you know how to convert from rectangular to polar notation?

Comment: yeah I know that

Comment: Do you know how to take powers and roots in polar notation?  It is much easier than  $a+bi$

Comment: On average you'll get more (and more usefu) answers if you show what you've tried.

Comment: @HAHAHA can you precise your answers for the powers? 5 and 1/2 are the exponents, but not the results.